# Java multithreaded server socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I tried to create a multithread server socket. It can either send a string for available file or a file as a stream. 
The problem is the else block, which sends requested file as a stream, works once. Where is the problem in my code and why it replies just once?

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {

Socket socket = null;

public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}


public void run() {
    try {
        String message = null;
        PrintStream ps = null;
        String string = null;
        File file = null;


        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        ps = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        while ((message = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {

            if (message.equals("list")) {
                ps.println(Arrays.toString(getServerFiles()));

            } else {
                message = "FilesServer\\" + message;
                file = new File(message);

                //JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    BufferedInputStream bfInStream =
                            new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(message));
                    BufferedOutputStream bufOutStream =
                            new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int read = 0;

                    while ((read = bfInStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        bufOutStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        bufOutStream.flush();
                    }
                    bufOutStream.close();
                    System.out.println("File transfered");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
}

private static String[] getServerFiles() {
    String result[];
    File folder = new File("FilesServer\\");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();



    result = new String[listOfFiles.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            result[i] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Above class is called from this class:

```
public class Server {

private int defaultPort = 8088;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new Server().InitServer();
}


private void InitServer() throws IOException{
    ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(8081);

    while(true){
        Socket socket = serversocket.accept();
        new ServerThread(socket).start();
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Calling `bufOutStream.close` is closing the underlying socket as well

Answer (score 0):

For server applications, you should use ServerSocket. ServerSocket must create new Socket each time new client requested a file (via accept() method). Then you send bytes into newly created socket and can safely close it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.but it has already been initiated from another class.

Answer (score 0):

Do not open and close the `BufferedOutputStream bufOutStream`. instead write directly to `ps` and close this after the while-loop.

closing bufOutStream closes the socket as MadProgrammer already mentioned.

Comment: Here's my code [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9RLwsPgO8cbQzR1WTQ5SXcyTnM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I checked your ServerThread and wrote a simple test. This test worked without (relevant) changes to your code. the "not relevant" was, that I just returned somes bytes from a ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes()) instead of the FileInputStream(message). It now seems to me, that there may be some other problems somewhere else in your stuff. but that is not related to your question here.